# Gatsby dynamic content and schema stitching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have the following graphql query that is executing at build time from my gatsby-node.js file that I'm using to bring in my article data. Is there a way to use Apollo/Axios to retrieve new articles without having to rebuild the site essentially rehydrating my site in between builds? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

I'm using Gatsby v2, Drupal as my CMS and GraphQL.

```
exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;
  const blogTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/blog-post.js');
  return graphql(`
  {
            blog: allNodeArticle{
        edges {
          node {
            id
            path {
              alias
            }
          }
        }
      }
  `
  ).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      Promise.reject(result.errors);
    }

    // Create blog pages
    result.data.blog.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.path.alias,
        component: blogTemplate,
        context: {
          alias: node.path.alias,
        },
      });
    });
  });
}
```

I would like to merge in the new data as it becomes available while keeping older data completely static (massive benefit of Gatsby)